# How to load JDBC driver for Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle-sqldeveloper

My professor asks us to make a **java** program that asks the user to input the data and the data inputted should automatically be inserted into a table in **sql developer**.

I have a background in Java and database but i'm not familiar with creating JDBC applications.

I searched a tutorial online and it said that i need to register the JDBC driver first. I ran the code in my compiler but it outputs `Error: unable to load driver class!`.

What should i do for it to register?

I still don't know the concept of `Class.forName();`

Secondly, it errors a `SQLException: No suitable drivers found`

I don't know what's wrong in my code but the connection details in my SQL developer is this:

> Connection name: mariel
>   
>  Connection details: mariel@//localhost:1521/XEXDB

The code:

```
import java.sql.* ; 
public class employeeMode{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws SQLException{
        String URL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XEXDB";
        String USER = "mariel";
        String PASS = "1234";
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASS);

        try {
           Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException ex) {
           System.out.println("Error: unable to load driver class!");
           System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:
I fixed it! Thank you everyone! here's the working code:

```
import java.sql.* ; 
public class employeeMode{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws SQLException{
        String URL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:mariel@//localhost:1521/XEXDB";
        String USER = "mariel";
        String PASS = "1234";


        try {
              Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
              Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASS);
            }
              catch(ClassNotFoundException ex) {
              System.out.println("Error: unable to load driver class!");
               System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to add oracle driver in your classpath

Comment: what kind of database are you using MySql or Oracle or something else. if you are using oracle use ojdbc.jar if you are using MySql use the jar that is provided along my installer

Comment: move your connection statement below line `Class.forName`

Comment: The line `Class.forName` is actually not needed since JDBC 4.

Comment: i'm using Oracle database 11g. I don't know how to add the oracle driver on my classpath. I moved the statement inside the try statement but it still does not found the driver. I'll find solution online on how to add the driver.

Answer (score 2):

@Mariel,
  have you installed Oracle 10g or any version Database,
i think Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"); is unable to find any database connection which you have installed your system

download ojdbcxxx.jar file from below drive 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html

Comment: i did add the classpath but it created another error. Is it because of the XEXDB service name?

Answer (score 2):

Add a jar that goes with the database

for oracle the connection string is

> jdbc:oracle:thin:`username`/`password`@`url`:`port`:`schema`

for Mysql follow the [link](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1322065?start=0&tstart=0)

Answer (score 1):

First you have to load the driver and then create the connection as below.
Also you have to put the ojdbc jar in the classpath.

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASS);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.sql.* ; 
public class employeeMode{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws SQLException{
        String URL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XEXDB";
        String USER = "mariel";
        String PASS = "1234";


        try {
              Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
              Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASS);
            }
              catch(ClassNotFoundException ex) {
              System.out.println("Error: unable to load driver class!");
               System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must have to add oracle driver jar file which is available on net http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/apps-tech/jdbc-112010-090769.html. then apply it in your class path.

Answer (score 1):

First you try to make the connection using drivermanager before load your oracle driver 
first you should add oracle ojdbc6-11.2.0.4.jar file to load the oracle driver

you can separate your two methods one to open and the second to close your database connection as below you

```
      public class BDConnection
      {
      private static final String DB_DRIVER =    "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XEXDB";
      private static final String DB_CONNECTION = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XEXDB";
      private static final String DB_USER = "mariel";
      private static final String DB_PASSWORD = "1234"; 

  }

   public static Connection getDBConnection() {

    Connection dbConnection = null;

    try {

        Class.forName(DB_DRIVER);

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

        System.out.println(e.getMessage());

    }

    try {

        return DriverManager.getConnection(
                DB_CONNECTION, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);



    } catch (SQLException e) {

        System.out.println(e.getMessage());

    }

    return dbConnection;

}

public static void closeMyConnection(Connection connection) {

    try {

        connection.close();


    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

And now to test your code just you shulod call getDBConnection() in your main method after adding your jar file

```
  public static void main(String[] argv) {

  Connection connection =getDBConnection();
  closeMyConnection(connection);        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
```

? And:

```
...
try {
       Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
       Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASS);
    }
...
```